# Unable to change SQL Server 2014 Listening Port

Tags: sql-server, tcp, sql-server-2014

I have got SQL Server installed and working fine. In order to allow firewalls, I went in to see that the instance I created is listening on dynamic port for each IP.

I went to TCP/IP Protocol properties, removed 0 for Dynamic Port from all IPs and added 1433 as TCP Port value.  I restarted SQL Server service.

But, SQL Server is listening on 54674 instead of 1433 even after restart.  I tried restarting the machine to just rule out I'm not missing any other service restart but of no use.

I tried changing port to 2001 and followed the same steps but the issue is same.

I ran below command

```
USE MASTER
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on'
GO
```

This gives me a little bit strange output

```
2017-01-06 14:32:25.580 spid17s      Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].
2017-01-06 14:32:25.580 spid17s      Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].
2017-01-06 14:32:25.580 spid17s      Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 2001].
2017-01-06 14:32:25.580 spid17s      Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 2001].
2017-01-06 14:32:25.580 Server       Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 54674].
2017-01-06 14:32:25.580 Server       Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 54674].
```

It looks like my changes to ports 1433 and then to 2001 has made `spid17s` to listen on but no effect on Server.  I am puzzled on what this `spid17s` is and why it is being shown here!!

I'm pretty much sure I did this many times in earlier versions successfully but not able to figure out what is so special in 2014, that I might be missing.

Please throw some pointers on fixing the issue.

Comment: If you want a dynamic port then you need 0 left there, or did you want to remove dynamic ports?

Comment: yes, I want to remove that port 54674 and make it listen on 1433 or any other custom port.  But, every time I tried, it didn't make effect on Server.